# how to select vanilla dom elements using reacts instead

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I select the following DOM elements using ReactJS. I am trying to convert those vanilla code to ReactJS

**html**

```
  <div class="top">
    <img src="images/ioootz-3.jpg" draggable="false" />
  </div>

  <div class="scroller scroller-middle">
    <svg
      class="scroller__thumb"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="100"
      height="100"
      viewBox="0 0 100 100"
    >
      <polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" style="fill:rgb(24,24,62)" />
      <polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" style="fill:rgb(24,24,62)" />
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="scroller scroller-top">
    <svg
      class="scroller__thumb"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="100"
      height="100"
      viewBox="0 0 100 100"
    >
      <polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" style="fill:rgb(24,24,62)" />
      <polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" style="fill:rgb(24,24,62)" />
    </svg>
  </div>
```

**javascripts code**

```
let scrollerMiddle = document.querySelector('.scroller-middle');
let scrollerTop = document.querySelector('.scroller-top');

document.querySelector('.middle').style.width = transform+5+"px";

scrollerMiddle.style.left = transform-20+"px";
scrollerTop.style.left = transform-30+"px";
```

so basically, how can I use useRef to select those DOM elements

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useRef` hook for this.

```
 function YourComponent() {
  const scrollerRef = useRef(null);

  // You can access the DOM element with scrollerRef.current

  return (
    <div className="scroller scroller-middle" ref={scrollerRef}>
      <svg
        className="scroller__thumb"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="100"
        height="100"
        viewBox="0 0 100 100"
      >
        <polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" style={{ fill: 'rgb(24,24,62)' }} />
        <polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" style={{ fill: 'rgb(24,24,62)' }} />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But seems like you just want to add some styles for the component. If that is the case, you use inline styling or css classes.

For example:

```
function YourComponent() {
  const [transform, setTransform] = useState(0);

  // Assuming you calculate the 'transform' value somehow

  const middleStyle = {
    width: transform + 5 + 'px',
  };

  const scrollerMiddleStyle = {
    left: transform - 20 + 'px',
  };

  const scrollerTopStyle = {
    left: transform - 30 + 'px',
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="middle" style={middleStyle}></div>
      <div className="scrollerMiddle" style={scrollerMiddleStyle}></div>
      <div className="scrollerTop" style={scrollerTopStyle}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: do you mind if I share my project?

Comment: this is the original projects https://github.com/okikiola12/vanilla-project

this is the converted project  https://github.com/okikiola12/codverrty